# How to jump to the specified frame in wireshark?

Tags: wireshark

My wireshark is up to filter some packages displayed.
[image]

Now i want to make wireshark display frame whose number is 318 ,how to make it jump to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some methods of displaying frame #318:

1. Clear the filter then select frame 318 with your mouse
2. Clear the filter then use **Go** -> **Go to packet** -> `318`
3. Clear the filter then use keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl-G</kbd> -> `318`.
4. Modify your filter to `tcp.stream eq 24 or frame.number eq 318`, then use one of the other 3 methods (mouse, menu, keyboard shortcut).